# Network engineering's background on Programmers adverts is less than ideal

Tags: bug, design

On the sidebar, this is what it looks like:

> [image]

Related from MSE from awhile back: [Confusing placement of popular network question above related questions in the sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239002/213963)

Please look at the other sites too, some of them have extremely pale backgrounds without borders that blend in too easily with our site's background.